# ¿Cómo obtengo el registro correspondiente a un id en un un arreglo json?

Tags: json, vue.js

disculpen...
El problema que tengo es que realizo peticiones a una api y me devuelve los datos en un objeto json, pero unos atributos son llaves foráneas y solamente es el id del registro relacionado, aunque, la api tiene implementado **HATEOAS** y muestra los enlaces para obtener esos recursos, aunque no sé cómo hacer para obtenerlos. La consulta a la api la estoy realizando a través de **axios** desde un componente de **vue**.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento en el componente:

**La tabla donde se muestran los regisrtos.**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Referencia</th>
            <th>Fecha de Ingreso</th>
            <th>Tipo documento</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="solicitud in listaSolicitudes" :key="solicitud.identificador">
            <td v-text="solicitud.codigoReferencia"></td>
            <td v-text="solicitud.fechaCreacion"></td>
            <td v-text="solicitud.tipoDocumento"></td>
            <td v-text="solicitud.usuario"></td>
            <td v-text="solicitud.estado"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**El script del componente.**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                listaSolicitudes: [],
                meta: [] // Aquí hay información de la paginación
            }
        },
        methods: {
            obtenerSolicitudes(){
                let me = this;
                var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/requests';
                axios.get(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    me.listaSolicitudes = response.data.data;
                    me.meta = response.data.meta
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.obtenerSolicitudes();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Este es un ejemplo del resultado del objeto json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "identificador": 1,
            "fecha": "1994-12-22",
            "codigoReferencia": "natus",
            "prioridad": "Normal",
            "estado": 5,
            "tipoDocumento": 4,
            "usuario": 1,
            "fechaCreacion": "2019-06-20 16:36:34",
            "fechaActualizacion": "2019-06-20 16:36:34",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/requests/1"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "status",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/statuses/5"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "document-type",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/document-types/4"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "user",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "identificador": 2,
            "fecha": "1971-08-02",
            "codigoReferencia": "sed",
            "prioridad": "Urgente",
            "estado": 1,
            "tipoDocumento": 7,
            "usuario": 6,
            "fechaCreacion": "2019-06-20 16:36:34",
            "fechaActualizacion": "2019-06-20 16:36:34",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/requests/2"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "status",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/statuses/1"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "document-type",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/document-types/7"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "user",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/6"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "total": 2,
            "count": 2,
            "per_page": 15,
            "current_page": 1,
            "total_pages": 1,
            "links": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Leí un poco que se podría obtener esos registros con una librería llamada traverson, pero no sé si se podría incluir con axios. Y si se puede no sé si me podrían mostrar un ejemplo, por favor. O tal vez me podrían explicar una manera alternativa de hacerlo.

Comment: Creo que entiendo tu problema, pero no termino de entender porque directamente no accedes al objeto listasolicitudes y despues recorres links (con sus respectivos for each) y dentro haces las llamadas... o eso es lo que no supiste hacer y me adelante.... No tenes que transformar el json a nada, axios lo hace solo al devolverlo en el data

Comment: Entendido, intentaré hacerlo de esa manera, gracias por la idea.

Comment: Intentalo. Si es asi, armamos una respuesta con eso

Comment: Lo intenté, pero ya que se realizan muchas consultas, se tarda demasiado para mostrar esos datos. Lo que hice fue modificar la api para que devuelva de una sola vez el elemento relacionado.

Comment: En paralelo y asincronicas tambien?